# Can I set the background color in a Firefox extension's popup notification?

Tags: javascript, firefox, popup, firefox-addon, xul

I am using the popup notification system described in the tutorial https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_popup_notifications . It is possible to change the background-color or text-color of the popup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example code in the documentation creates a `<popupnotification popupid="sample-popup">` tag in the browser window (obviously, `popupid` attribute depends on the ID you specified when opening the notification), you can style it. Add the following code to a CSS file [loaded by your browser overlay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Adding_Style_Sheets):

```css
popupnotification[popupid="sample-popup"]
{
  background-color: #123456;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would also like to know if I can add multiple rows in the title area(the parameter after notification id), something like <br/> (which isn't working). Thanks again.

Comment: @user1256960 : As per ‘Wladimir's‘ answer it should work. If not then you can go for custom popup notification. <http://www.cs.virginia.edu/felt/cs493/ext/extension_guide_3.pdf> <http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Popup-js.html>

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can change the colors, search for a stylesheet file to change the styling as per your requirements.