# Customize popup notification in firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, xul

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I set the background color in a Firefox extension's popup notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617562/can-i-set-the-background-color-in-a-firefox-extensions-popup-notification)

I have a question regarding this tutorial https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_popup_notifications . I am curious if I can customize the dropdown box and the border from the notification and how can I add the link like in the first screenshot..Thank you

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times.

Comment: Let's close this. Definitely exact duplicate from same user.